# Using Get-childitem to get a list of files modified in the last 3 days

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Code as it is at the moment

```
get-childitem c:\pstbak\*.* -include *.pst | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-3)} |
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is get a list of all PST files in the folder above based on  them being newer than 3 days old. I'd then like to count the results. The above code doesn't error but brings back zero results (there are definitely PST files in the folder that are newer than three days. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: change `-lt` in `-gt` for file modified in the last 3 days from now..

Comment: A note for others wondering why we're filtering after capturing all results rather than using the `-Filter` parameter.  `Filter` on this cmdlet takes a mask against which the `Path` is compared; it does not allow you to filter on other properties as you may expect from having used this parameter on other cmdlets.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try this:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path c:\pstbak\*.* -Filter *.pst | ? {
  $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) 
}).Count
```

Answer (score 34):

Very similar to previous responses, but the is from the current directory, looks at any file and only for ones that are 4 days old.  This is what I needed for my research and the above answers were all very helpful.  Thanks.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse| ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-4)}
```

Comment: Same command not using the ? alias:    `Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse| Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-4)}`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minor update to the solution provided by Dave Sexton. Many times you need multiple filters. The Filter parameter can only take a single string whereas the -Include parameter can take a string array. if you have a large file tree it also makes sense to only get the date to compare with once, not for each file. Here's my updated version:

```
$compareDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)    
@(Get-ChildItem -Path c:\pstbak\*.* -Filter '*.pst','*.mdb' -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $compareDate}).Count
```

Comment: You mention the `-Filter` parameter can only take a single string but you're passing an array of file types into it ( `'*.pst','*.mdb'` ).  Is that intentional or did you mean to use the `-Include` parameter instead?

Comment: Ah, good catch @SimonElms !

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to just add this as a comment to the previous answer, but I can't. I tried [Dave Sexton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1419175/dave-sexton)'s answer but had problems if the count was 1.  This forces an array even if one object is returned.

```
([System.Object[]](gci c:\pstback\ -Filter *.pst | 
    ? { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)})).Count
```

It still doesn't return zero if empty, but testing '-lt 1' works.

Comment: To force an array as the return object use @ rather than [System.Object[]]. You could also use [array] as another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

By the title of the question the answer to find every file modified today is:
Get-ChildItem -Path .*.pst| ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)}

Modified in the last three days:
Get-ChildItem -Path .*.pst| ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)}

Modified in the last three days and count:
(Get-ChildItem -Path .*.pst| ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)}).count

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the files and not only count them:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Program Files\*.*" -Recurse | 
Foreach {
$lastupdatetime=$_.LastWriteTime
$nowtime = get-date
if (($nowtime - $lastupdatetime).totaldays -le 3)
{
Write-Host "File modified: "$_
}
}
```

Key factor is to use `"` to avoid problems with spaces, fact which nobody else mentioned. Replace `C:\Program Files` with any path you like. If you want only the name use `$_.Name` instead of `$_`.